# Which annotation is preferable to use before @Test annotation in testNG for Page Object Model?

Tags: selenium, testng

I'm running my selenium code for Page object model using testNG, @BeforeTest will run only once for every test and @BeforeMethod will run everytime for every test. So which annotation would be preferable to use for page object model ?

```
@BeforeMethod
public void setUp() throws IOException
{
  initialisation();
  loginPage = new Login();
  loginPage.login(prop.getProperty("username"), prop.getProperty("password"));
  ot = new OpenTasks();
  active = new ActiveProjects();
}


@Test(priority=1)
  public void validateTitle() throws IOException, InterruptedException
  {
    String custTitle = ot.verifyTitle();
    Assert.assertEquals(custTitle, "actiTIME - Open Tasks", "Title not matched");
  }


@Test(priority=2)
  public void verifyProjectLink() throws IOException, InterruptedException
  {
   active = ot.clickOnProjectLink();
 }

 @AfterMethod
  public void tearDown()
  {
    driver.quit(); 
 }
```

(or)

```
public static WebDriver driver;
    @BeforeTest
    public void preConfig()
    {
        if(browser.equals("firefox"))
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Program Files\\FireFox\\geckodriver-v0.24.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
            driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        }
        if(browser.equals("chrome"))
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Program Files\\Chrome\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver=new ChromeDriver();
        }
         driver.get("http://desktop-g53h9ip:81/login.do");
         driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }
    @AfterTest
    public void postConfig()
    {
        driver.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to instantiate browser once for a single test and 2nd approach is better approach for any kind of framework.

Answer (score 0):

Following structure for TestNG annotations

```
@BeforeSuite
@BeforeTest
@BeforeClass
@BeforeMethod
@Test
@AfterMethod
@AfterClass
@AfterTest
@AfterSuite
```